# Existence of MLE

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have a problem with MLE's definition:

Casella Berger in *Statistical Inference* and Nitis Mukhopadhyay in *Probability and Statistics* said that MLE for a parameter $\theta\in\Theta$ is respectively $\arg\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}\{L(\theta\mid x)\}$ or $\arg\max_{\theta\in\Theta}\{L(\theta\mid x)\}$.

But this estimator is a supremum or a maximum? If it is a supremum why we don't call it supremum likelihood estimator? Conversely if it is a maximum, the likelihood function must be continuous and the parametric space must be compact (sufficient condition for the existence of maximum)

What is the truth or the minimal condition for the existence of MLE?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a "supremum" and a "maximum"?  Any set of real numbers, having an upper bound, as a supremum but not necessarily a maximum.  A set of real numbers has a maximum if and only if the supremum is in the set in which case the maximum **is** the supremum.

Comment: Of course I know the difference. My problem is that in an estimation, the estimate parameter must belong to the parametric space but if the parametric space is for example an open set,  the supremum may stay in its boundary and this thing may has no sense.  So I want to understand which is the correct definition of MLE; there is argsup or argmax? because the second one may not belong to the parametric space. Thanks

Comment: Then you realize that if the maximum [b]exists[/b], there is no difference between the two.  If the maximum does not exist, then you [b]have[/b] to use the supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficient conditions for the MLE to exist are $L$ continuous in $\theta$ over a compact support (extreme value theorem).
We can built an example where the maximum in $\theta$ does not exist, but the supremum does. The main open difficulty is whether the "supremum likelihood" is meaningful...
If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $\theta=(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are parameters, then the likelihood (for one observation) is $$ L(\theta)=\frac{1}{b-a} \hspace{4mm} \text{ if } a<u_i<b $$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the MLE does not exist, but the SLE does (but is not unique…). See for instance the lecture notes of Songfeng Zheng (p. 5 and 6) for a discussion:
http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/MLE.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much: I've searching this example and now I've understand the problem thanks to the discussion in the lecture notes.

Comment: It helps me out, too!