# Can some System of Equations not be Solved using Derivatives?

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization

Suppose we consider the Gaussian (Normal) Probability Distribution Function:

$$f(x|\mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

Suppose we are interested in estimating $\mu, \sigma^2$. We usually do this by writing the likelihood function, taking the derivatives with respect to $\mu, \sigma^2$ and solving these derivatives:

$$L(\mu, \sigma^2 | x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i | \mu, \sigma^2)$$
$$l(\mu, \sigma^2 | x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln f(x_i | \mu, \sigma^2)$$

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} = 0 \\$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2} = 0$$

**My Question:** In the above situation, these two equations are solvable analytically. In some other more complex situations, the resulting equations are still solvable - but need to be solved iteratively using some numerical algorithm. **But can there ever arise certain situations where the above such equations are fundamentally not solvable mathematically?**

For example, perhaps one of the derivatives with respect to one of the variables cancels out  completely and the parameter can not be estimated(e.g. derivative of 2x is 2, x can not be solved)? Are there any such situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at example 1 of ["Maximum Likelihood, an introduction"](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ezwp/teach/Math-Stat/MLE1.pdf). It considers a gaussian mixture where one of the means fall onto an observation, leading to cancellation and divergence of the variance estimator.

Moreover, this previously existing thread is closely related to your question, you might want to check it out as well. [When does a maximum likelihood estimate fail to exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85782/when-does-a-maximum-likelihood-estimate-fail-to-exist)

Second Edit to clarify the gaussian mixture example:

Consider one realisation of a Random Variable $X$ distributed as follow : $f(x,\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1-\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \hbox{exp}[-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2] + \frac{\alpha}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\hbox{exp}[-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma}]$, where $\mu$ is fixed.

Suppose the observation $x_1$ is equal to $\mu$ (this happens with null probability but is nonetheless a valid case). The Likelihood function with respect to $\sigma$ is then

$$L(\sigma) = \frac{1-\alpha}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}}1 + \frac{\alpha}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} 1$$

Derivating and trying to egalize $0$ yields:

$$- \frac{\alpha}{\sigma^2 \sqrt{2\pi}} = 0 $$

Which is unsolvable, as it diverges to infinity.

Edited to add:

Another example where this time the derivatives are indeed not solvable, but where you can still find a solution, is the following (taken from [Here](http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/MLE.pdf) and coming from [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059667/existence-of-mle):

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,\theta]$.

The Likelihood function is therefore

$$L(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^n} 1_{x_{1,\dots,n} \in [0,\theta]}$$

Derivating this with respect to $\theta$ and trying to solve to $0$ cannot be done, however, by looking at the likelihood function, you can still maximize it by taking $\hat{\theta} = \underset{i}{\hbox{max}}(x_i)$.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I actually consulted the question you linked prior to posting. That question only gave an example of a gaussian mixture model (gmm) ... in a gmm, the likelihood does exist but is intractable due to its complex nature. But I am looking for examples where the likelihood simply does not exist. Thank you so much!

Comment: My older question on this topic

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796679/why-is-this-optimization-problem-difficult

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802389/does-the-word-tractable-have-an-exact-meaning-in-math

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803163/why-is-gradient-descent-always-chosen-for-neural-networks

Comment: ". It considers a gaussian mixture where one of the means fall onto an observation, leading to cancellation and divergence of the variance estimator.". I have heard this point mentioned in the past but have never been able to fully understand it. If you have time, can you please explain this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've edited my answer with perhaps an answer more to your liking.

Comment: Added a second edit to attempt to explain this part !